# Как преобразовать Date в Raw ? На PL/Sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Существует процедура dbms_stats.convert_raw_value, которая может преобразовать Raw в Date. А как наоборот преобразовать значение типа Date в Raw ?

Oracle Database 11g.